# Echo binary data in php so that Java code

Tags: java, php, binary

I want to read binary data from file and send it to remote Java App.
As I found [here](http://blog-en.openalfa.com/how-to-work-with-binary-data-in-php):
I can get it like this (part of my code):

```
else
{
    $fp = fopen("binary file","rb");
    $vector="";
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        // Read the file, in chunks of 16 byte
        $data = fread($fp,16);
        $arr = unpack("C*",$data);
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            $vector.=" ".$value;
        }
        $vector.="\n";
    }
}
```

I send some headers

```
header("Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=bounary----I don't know if boundary value is private".$eol);
    header("MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol);
    header("Connection: Keep-Alive".$eol);
    header("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate".$eol);
    header("Host: host".$eol.$eol);
    header("Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=bounary----I don't know if boundary value is private".$eol);
    header("Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=bounary----I don't know if boundary value is private".$eol);
```

Then I print it like this:

```
echo "--".$BOUNDARY.$eol;
echo "Content-Type: application/octet-stream".$eol;
echo "Content-Length: ".strlen($vector).$eol;
echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary".$eol;
echo $eol.$vector.$eol;
echo "--".$BOUNDARY."--".$eol;
```

I test it in Advanced Rest Client Application and see binary data:

```
0 0 0 72 0 54 0 55 0 97 0 56 0 51 0 49
 0 101 0 56 0 45 0 53 0 102 0 48 0 56 0 45
 0 52 0 100 0 49 0 99 0 45 0 97 0 57 0 57
 0 52 0 45 0 101 0 101 0 53 0 97 0 51 0 52
 0 49 0 52 0 50 0 54 0 57 0 51 0 0 0 1
 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0...
```

But Java coder sayas that there is an empty string instead of binary data? How can I echo this binary data in proper way? What can cause this problem?

**Update**: We've found, that no matter what Content-Length header I set, in his app he receives header: Content-Length: 475
However in Advanced Rest Client I see my value of content-length. Well it can cause the problem. Can it be caused by php somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the 2 `$eol`'s in this line is causing the subsequent headers to not be sent:

```
header("Host: host".$eol.$eol);
```

Try changing it to 1, or in fact I doubt you even need the EOL char in the string you send to header().